# One Column to extend to edge of the window and other Column to remain within container

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a two-column layout where the column on the left is 40% of the container and stays/aligns with the container but the column on the right expands to the edge of the window. I am able to do it with position absolute but I am sure there are better ways to do it. Following is the image and the code snippet of what I did. Is there a better way to do the same thing?

[image]

```css
div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: #EEE;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.container.wide {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: unset;
}

.relativediv {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.container.wide :nth-child(1) {
  width: 40%;
}

.container.wide :nth-child(2) {
  width: 60%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.container.wide :nth-child(2) img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="relativediv">

  <div class="container wide">
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744.jpg?hmac=3GAAioiQziMGEtLbfrdbcoenXoWAW-zlyEAMkfEdBzQ" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why do you use a hacky positioning instead of keeping it simple with either `flexbox` or `css-grid`?

Comment: yes thats the hacky way and I don't like. Want to do it with CSS grid or flexbox But I don't know how to do that and I am not able to find an example anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use Flexbox to create a 2 column layout. To center the text vertically inside your left column, you can use flexbox too:

```css
.relativediv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.absolute-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="relativediv">

  <div class="container wide">
    <div></div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744.jpg?hmac=3GAAioiQziMGEtLbfrdbcoenXoWAW-zlyEAMkfEdBzQ" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute-container">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit smit is dummy text. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thats not what i want. Lets say windows width is 1400 and i have a container with width 1000px. I want column on left to align with 1000px container and other column to expand until the edge of the window.

Comment: then change the width to 1000px and use `flex-grow: 1` to occupy the remaining space on the other container. Then you also have to say it within your question. Your question only speakd of 40% for the left column...